# PHP: Undefined method error even when using class autoloader?

Tags: php, autoload

I'm trying to make a class that manages all the data I store into the `$_SESSION` global array.
So far, I've been using a script that uses `spl_autoload_register` to load my classes.

Here's my autoload script (in php/scripts/classLoader.php):

```
<?php

spl_autoload_register('loadUtils');

function loadUtils($class)
{
    $path = "php\\classes\\utils\\";
    $extension = ".php";
    include_once($path . $class . $extension);
}
```

Here's my SessionHandler class (in php/classes/utils/SessionHandler.php)

```
<?php
class SessionHandler
{
    private const PARAMS = [
         "USER" => "user-data",
         "ADMIN" => "admin-data",
         "ALERTS" => "alert-options",
    ];

    public static function startSession()
    {
        session_start();
    }

    public static function setAlertOptions(AlertOptions $ao)
    {
        $_SESSION[self::PARAMS["ALERTS"]] = $ao;
    }

    public static function getAlertOptions(): AlertOptions
    {
        return $_SESSION[self::PARAMS["ALERTS"]] ?? new AlertOptions();
    }
}
```

Here is, by request, AlertHandler class (php/classes/utils/AlertHandler.php)
Note that the last two methods are for getting and storing data from and into $_SESSION, which used to work fine before implementing the SessionHandler.

```
class AlertHandler
{
    private const PARAM_NAME = "alert-options";

    public static function showAlert()
    {
        $_alertOptions = self::getFromSession();
        $_message = $_alertOptions->message;
        $_show = $_alertOptions->show;

        if ($_message && $_show) {
            echo <<<ERROR
            <div class="container mt-3 alert alert-primary align-self-stretch">
                {$_message}
            </div>
            ERROR;
        }

        //reset error status
        self::setIntoSession(new AlertOptions());
    }

    public static function setMessage(string $message = "")
    {
        $_alertOptions = SessionHandler::getAlertOptions();
        $_alertOptions->message = $message ?? "";
        SessionHandler::setAlertOptions($_alertOptions);
    }

    public static function toggle(?bool $state = null)
    {
        $_alertOptions = SessionHandler::getAlertOptions();
        $_alertOptions->show = $state ?? !$_alertOptions->show;
        SessionHandler::setAlertOptions($_alertOptions);
    }

    public static function handleException(
        Exception $e,
        string $redirect = "index.php",
    ) {
        self::setMessage("Error: {$e->getMessage()} En: {$e->getFile()}, línea {$e->getLine()}");
        self::toggle(true);
        header("Location: $redirect");
    }

    private static function getFromSession(): AlertOptions
    {
        return $_SESSION[self::PARAM_NAME] ?? new AlertOptions();
    }

    private static function setIntoSession(AlertOptions $ao)
    {
        $_SESSION[self::PARAM_NAME] = $ao;
    }
}
```

Finally, here's my index.php:

```
<?php
//PHP Scripts
include_once('php/scripts/classLoader.php');
include_once('php/scripts/errorHandler.php');
?>

<?php include_once('php/components/Header.php'); ?>


<body class="d-flex flex-column">
    <?php include_once('php/components/Navbar.php') ?>

    <?= SessionHandler::startSession() ?>
    <?= AlertHandler::showAlert(); ?>

    <div id="main" class="d-flex flex-fill align-items-center justify-content-center">
        <?php try {
            Router::redirect($_GET['location'] ?? null);
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            AlertHandler::handleException($e);
        } ?>
    </div>
</body>
```

Whenever I call any method from SessionHandler, I get the the following error: `Call to undefined method SessionHandler::[method]`.

Comment: `SessionHandler::startSession()` doesn't return anything. What did you expect to print out from that call?  I don't see where `AlertHandler::showAlert()` is defined.  Starting a session should be the very, very first thing that your script does (unconditionally) to maintain the session.

Comment: @mickmackusa I expected it to return nothing. `AlertHandler::showAlert()` does not returns anything either, it echoes a alert div if aplicable. I will update the comment to show it.